# Combine unique values into a single row. in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions, distinct

I have got this table named students that contains the department and the age of the students. Each row represents the student's department and their respective age.

| department | age |
| --- | --- |
| Civil Engineering | 19 |
| Civil Engineering | 20 |
| Statistics | 19 |
| Statistics | 19 |
| Mechanical Engineering | 21 |
| Mechanical Engineering | 20 |
| Computer Science | 25 |
| Computer Science | 24 |
| Civil Engineering | 21 |
| Civil Engineering | 22 |
| Statistics | 20 |
| Mechanical Engineering | 20 |

Now, I need to find the count of unique age in each department and also in the third column list all the unique ages corresponding to that department.
The output should look like this:

| department | count_unique _age | unique_ages |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Civil Engineering | 4 | 19,20,21,22 |
| Statistics | 2 | 19,20 |
| Mechanical Engineering | 2 | 20,21 |
| Computer Science | 2 | 24,25 |

Query I have tried -

```
SELECT DISTINCT department, COUNT(DISTINCT age) AS count_unique_age, 
FROM students
GROUP BY department
```

Using this query I am able to solve the first two columns. How do I solve for the third column?

Answer (score 1):

That’s a simple aggregate query; in MySQL, we can use `group_concat` for string aggregation.

```
select department,
    count(distinct age) count_unique_age,
    group_concat(distinct age order by age separator ', ') distinct_ages
from mytable
group by department
```

As we only count distinct values, I wonder whether it might be more efficient to deduplicate in a subquery first:

```
select department,
    count(age) count_unique_age,
    group_concat(age order by age separator ', ') distinct_ages
from (select distinct department, age from mytable) t
group by department
```